# Change an argument in kakoune

Tags: kakoune

Is there any easy way to select/change/delete an argument in kakoune?

For example, if I have

```
int foo(int arg1, int arg2)
```

and I would like to select `int arg1`.  In spacemacs I can do this with `via`. How do I do this in kakoune?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `u` text-object.
So, while inside the parens type `<a-i>u`.

If you do `<a-a>u` instead, it will also select the following comma and space.